# jQuery - animate a div without deforming the content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Is there a way with jQuery to animate a div without its contents being deformed?

Let my example speak for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/v2uHf/4/

In my resizedivs function:

```
function resizedivs() {
    $("#div_3B").animate({
        "width": "0"
    }, 700, function () {

        $("#div_3A").animate({
            "width": "20%"
        }, 700, function () {
            $("#div_3B").animate({
                "width": "80%"
            }, 700);
        });
    });
}
```

I'd like the strings in the div_3B to stay on their own lines, without going on a new line as in a word-wrap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rather animate the positions than the widths in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to #div_3B (you've already added `overflow: hidden;`):

http://jsfiddle.net/v2uHf/6/

Comment: What if I need to write a long paragraph without having to put it in different lines?

Check this updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/v2uHf/10/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/v2uHf/8/

```
      white-space: nowrap;
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

change your 



 element style to this

```
<p style="white-space: nowrap;">I don't want this strings to deform</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `white-space: nowrap` solution is that it affects to div's makeup. I would advise to wrap content with new div and set fixed width to it (using `$("#div_3B").width()`). Plus you need to add `overflow: hidden` to `#div_3B`. It can be done inside of `resizedivs` function. When animation will complete you can cleanup extra div.